# subprocess.popen and subprocess.run when calling another file.py gives import error on linux. Python 3.6.4

Tags: python, subprocess, python-import

subprocess.popen and subprocess.run, when calling "file.py", both gives import error on Linux. Python 3.6.4 on Linux. Python 3.6.5 on Windows. Windows works without issue. Linux throws the error. The calls are intended to be independent and invisible to the original process/script.

For Linux (either of the following lines):

```
  proc = subprocess.run("python3 foo.py", shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
  proc = subprocess.Popen("python3 foo.py", shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

For Windows (either of the following lines):

```
  proc = subprocess.run("python bar.py", shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
  proc = subprocess.Popen("python bar.py", shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

Also, note that running the individual scripts work without incident; it's only when you call it from another script that it gives the errors. Any Ideas?

EDIT:
For example, let's say that this is foo.py:

```
  import requests, urllib.request as urllib2, wget, ftplib, sys, tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk, serial, threading, platform, time, socket, os, json, struct, logging, pickle, re, queue, subprocess, uuid, netifaces as nif, zipfile, ctypes
  from platform import system as OS_VER
  from PIL import Image, ImageTk


  LibList = [requests, urllib2, wget, ftplib, sys, tk, ttk, serial, threading, platform, time, socket, os, json, struct, logging, pickle, re, queue, subprocess, uuid, nif, zipfile, ctypes, Image, ImageTk, platform]

  for x in range(len(LibList)):
     try: print(LibList[x].__file__)
     except: print(LibList[x])
```

And this is bar.py

```
  proc = subprocess.Popen("python3 foo.py", shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

Run bar.py  and foo.py gets an error on Linux but not on windows. 
Skip bar.py and run foo.py directly works fine though on Linux.

Comment: These both give an `AttributeError`, because there's nothing called `subprocess.popen`. Also, the Windows one runs two different scripts, and runs one of them with `python` and the other with `python3`, while Linux runs the same script with the same interpreter in both. And none of them run something named `file.py`, which makes it pretty hard to debug whatever error you're having with `file.py`.

Comment: That was actually a typo and is fixed now. names of the scripts are generic.

Comment: Is `python3` guaranteed to be the same Python installation you're using to run this script? (Usually, you use `sys.executable` instead of `"python3"`. And of course you don't use `shell=True` if you don't need it. But if you want to do it the hard way, you have to manually verify that it has the same effect anyway, because we can't check that for you.)

Comment: yes it should be. tried sys.executable as well with no change.

Comment: It works in Linux only with the live python interpreter.  'subprocess.Popen("/home/<user>/Documents/foo.py")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to create a shell script and call it with `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.run`.

example: 
`subprocess.Popen('Foo.sh')`

and the Foo.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python3 Foo.py > log.log &
```

The & is needed to fork the process in Linux. Otherwise, it is blocking and will not proceed until closed.